# Difference between 'regarding' and 'according to'

Tags: word-difference, exam-questions

While I was answering some grammar tests, I came across this :

> (Blank) the patient's condition, the doctor decided to operate .

Our teacher says 'regarding' is the correct choice but I can find no reason as to why 'according to' might be incorrect.
Please explain the difference between 'regarding' and 'according to' ? Is it always possible to use these two interchangeably ?

Comment: Its not a duplicate i already checked the post that you mentioned as a duplicate of the one i posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really interesting question. The meanings are similar, but not quite the same. I think your teacher is correct.

*According to* and *regarding* can have similar meanings. One meaning of *according to* is:

> *3* if something varies according to a changing factor, it varies in a way that is determined by this factor ([Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/according-to))

For example:

> *When getting ready for a long jog, choose your clothes according to the weather*.

This means a jogger should wear lightweight clothing in the heat, and warmer clothing in the colder weather.

With that in mind, I suppose you could say:

> *The doctor decided to operate according to the patient's condition*.

However, that's a somewhat odd sentence. I'd interpret it to mean that the *way* the doctor chose to operate varied somehow, depending on the condition of the patient (for example, some patients require full anesthesia, while others only require a local anesthetic). I think that sentence seems even more strange with the *according to* is moved to the front of the sentence:

> *According to the patient's condition, the doctor decided to operate*.

Looking at all three of Macmillan's definitions of *according to*, none of them seem to be a good fit:

> *1* if you do something according to a plan, system, or set of rules, you do it in a way that agrees with or obeys that plan, system, or set of rules
>
> *2* used for saying where information or ideas have come from

*Regarding* is a more general word that means *concerning*:

> *Regarding the patient's condition, the doctor decided to operate*.

This means that the doctor evaluated the patient's condition, and decided to operate.

Answer (score 3):

> regarding

means *in reference to*.

> according to

is used to cite a specific source of information. Some examples:

> *Regarding* the patients condition, the best course of action *according to* the doctor is to operate.
>
> *Regarding* the meaning of the word *help*, *according to* the dictionary it means "to aide".